# Using Grails 1.2.0 and Spock 0.4-SNAPSHOT - Compilation errors

Tags: maven-2, grails, compilation, ivy

Using Grails 1.2.0 and the latest Spock 0.4-SNAPSHOT (as of 01/28/2010 10:18 EST) I'm getting compilation errors that the Groovy compiler is unable to find:

**org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie**
and
**org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair**

No matter what I've tried (adding it as a dep in the plugin, adding it as a dep in the app) it returns the exact same error. This happens in the console using, specifically, grails test-app.

I've also tried deleting the .grails directory, the .ivy2 directory and even my .m2 directory to clean out the dependencies in case that is the problem.

Comment: More info: I noticed that in both my .ivy2 and .m2 directories both commons-codec and commons-httpclient have empty jars.

Copying them in from their sources seems to be working. Must be a problem with the maven repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jars are actually HTML files in my repository because of this Maven bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4428